# Loop unable to terminate while reading input through pipe in child process

Tags: c, pipe, fork, system-calls, child-process

I am working on pipe implementation using C. I have to write the C equivalent of (grep -rF regex directory | tee output.txt | wc -l). However the code is unable to proceed beyond the tee equivalent. (the loop marked in the following code never terminates). I do not understand why the loop does not terminate and why the output of pipe is not passed to input of `newpipe`.

When I remove the while loop, the program terminates with the output as 0.

```
    int newpipe[2],p[2],pid;
    char * argv_list1[] = {"grep","-rF","regex","directory",NULL};
    char * argv_list2[] = {"wc","-l",NULL};
    char *file="output.txt";
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){
        int pid2=fork();
        if(pid2==0){
            close(p[0]);
            dup2(p[1],1);
            execvp("grep",argv_list1);
        }
        else{
            wait(NULL);
            int fd=open(file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT |O_TRUNC,0666);
            close(newpipe[0]);
            close(p[1]);
            dup2(p[0], 0);
            printf("pid2=%d\n",pid2);
            dup2(newpipe[1],1);
            char tmp;
            while(read(p[0],&tmp,1)){
                write(fd,&tmp,1);
                write(1,&tmp,1);
            }//This loop never terminates and the output comes on standard output
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else{
        wait(NULL);
        close(newpipe[1]);
        dup2(newpipe[0],0);
        execvp("wc",argv_list2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as posted, never calls pipe() to create the pipes; so that is a problem, but after it does, you have a bit more fd work to do.

In your *first* child, the one that exec()'s grep, you properly close p[0], and dup the write end (p[1]) to STDOUT_FILENO (btw, a bit more descriptive than 1), but don't close p[1]; dup2 is like a copy not a move.   This leaves it dangling.   You will likely create newpipe at the outer most process, so you will have to close both ends of it here.

The same applies for the *tee*, it needs to shut down its unused fds, and for the *wc* process as well.

You need to remove the *wait*s, they are masking some of the fd-handling bugs.   Btw, note that in *tee*, you dup2'd p[0] to 0, then read from p[0].  Dangling pipes will not generate EOF.

The fd handling around pipe() and fork() is always cumbersome.  Account for each one in each processes.